# Can Windows Update force a system restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have an Acer Veriton with Windows 7. Up until recently, I was used to seeing updates kick in after shutting down the system. However, one night, my computer shut down by itself and then installed an update. Is this normal behaviour ? What kind of updates does it concern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour when installing updates to the kernel or drivers.

Comment: Ok, great. I was afraid this was a forced reboot as used to be hapen with a vulnerabity on Windows 2000.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly normal for certain updates because windows can not configure them while windows is running. Once windows installs them by default it will force reboot in 10 minutes, but you can delay it 1 hour or even 4 hours. After your computer reboots and before windows starts up again it will configure them (while windows is not using those files).

I hope that helps!